# How to filter a list if a specific value isn't on another list of different type

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, collections

let's say we have two objects and lists of each one.

```
class Brand(val id: Int, val name: String)
class Car(val id: Int, val name: String, val brandID: Int)   

val cars: List<Car> = listOf(Car(1, 11), Car(2, 13))
val brands: List<Brand> = listOf(Brand(11, "BMW"), Brand(12, "Ford"), Brand(13, "Tesla"))
```

What I want to achieve is to filter the brands' list to show only the brands that are associated with the cars list and by the mentioned example the brand "Ford" should be removed from the list.

here's what the two solutions that I did and none of them worked out.

```
val filterdBrandsA = brands.filter { b -> cars.any { it.brandID == b.id } }
// filterdBrandsA size always = 0 ??

val filterdBrandsB = brands.filter { b -> cars.map { it.brandID }.contains(b.id) }
// filterdBrandsB size always = 0 ??
```

---

**so what did I do wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your code in a scratch file and the solution it was to use "flatMap":

```
class Brand(val id: Int, val name: String)
class Car(val id: Int, val name: String, val brandID: Int)

val cars: List<Car> = listOf(
    Car(id = 1, name = "", brandID = 11),
    Car(id = 2, name = "", brandID = 13)
)
val brands: List<Brand> = listOf(
    Brand(id = 11, name = "BMW"),
    Brand(id = 12, name = "Ford"),
    Brand(id = 13, name = "Tesla")
)

val result = cars.flatMap { 
    brands.filter { brand -> brand.id == it.brandID }
}

result.forEach { 
    println(it.name) // result: BMW and Tesla
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems nice and simple:

```
val filterdBrandsA = brands.filter{ b -> b.id in cars.map{it.brandID}}
```